# Changing Read Parsing Script from .csv to .xls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, xls

I have an existing script that parses a csv file... but my source has started sending xls files now...

Any suggestions on changeing this script to parse xls files.

```
def parse_csv(filename)
  lines = CSV.read(filename)
  header = lines.shift
  raise EdiLoadsFileEmpty if header.nil?
  posts = []
  lines.each do |line|
    post = Hash[header.zip line]
    posts.push post
  end
  posts
end
```

this is what i have now Steve

def parse_csv(filename)
      workbook = Roo::Excel.new(filename)
      workbook.default_sheet = workbook.sheets[0]
      header = workbook.row(1)
      raise EdiLoadsFileEmpty if header.nil?
      puts header
      posts = []
      (2..workbook.last_row).each do |i|
        post = Hash[header.zip (workbook.row(i))]
        posts << post
      end
      posts
    end

works for me just reformated the dates from 7/18/2014 to Fri, 18 Jul 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'roo' gem opens Excel, Excelx, Google spreadsheets, OpenOffice, and CSV.

```
if File.extname(filename) == "xls"
  workbook = Roo::Excel.new(filename)  
else
  workbook = Roo::CSV.new(filename)
end
workbook.default_sheet = workbook.sheets[0]
```

Then use the `workbook.row` method to process each row

```
((workbook.first_row + 1)..workbook.last_row).each do |lines|
...
end
```

EDIT I recall there's an issue with `each` and the roo gem... try this

```
(2..workbook.last_row).each do |i|
  post = Hash[header.zip(workbook.row(i))]
  posts << post
end
```

Comment: so would i be able to still grab the header in that block like i already do?

Comment: Yes, you can't shift I don't think (at least I never tried it) but it'll be workbook.row(1) so just do `header = workbook.row(1)` and then you just iterate through rows 2 through to `workbook.last_row`.

Comment: NameError: undefined local variable or method `i' for EdiLoads:Class

Comment: darn darn ... change the first occurence of `i` to `|i|` (see my edited answer)  sorry about that.

Comment: updated my post agian... now it passes it... but parses no data

Comment: So are you saying the method returns nil? Can you inspect or print the contents of `header` and the lines?

Comment: Have you ever used the 'pry' gem?

Comment: nevermind it works but reformated dates... changed 7/18/2014  to Fri, 18 Jul 2014

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it (checkbox to the left of the answer).  Cheers